# CGImage float format requires byte swapping?

Tags: floating-point, pixel, cgimage, endianness

I am doing some image processing work which requires floating point grayscale image data. The method `-imagePlanarFData:` below is presently how I'm extracting this data from an input `CIImage`:

```
- (NSData *)byteswapPlanarFData:(NSData *)data
                    swapInPlace:(BOOL)swapInPlace;
{
    NSData * outputData = swapInPlace ? data : [data mutableCopy];
    const int32_t * image = [outputData bytes];
    size_t length = [outputData length] / sizeof(*image);
    for (int i = 0;
         i < length;
         i++) {
        int32_t * val = (int32_t *)&image[i];
        *val = OSSwapBigToHostInt32(*val);
    }
    return outputData;
}

- (NSData *)imagePlanarFData:(CIImage *)processedImage;
{
    NSSize size = [processedImage extent].size;
    if (size.width == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    dispatch_once(&_onceToken, ^ {
        _colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGray);
        _bytesPerRow = size.width * sizeof(float);
        _cgx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 32, _bytesPerRow, _colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapFloatComponents);
        // Work-around for CIImage drawing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running with Guard Malloc;
        // see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689233/ciimage-drawing-exc-bad-access>
        NSDictionary * options = nil;
        if (getenv("MallocStackLogging") || getenv("MallocStackLoggingNoCompact")) {
            NSLog(@"Forcing CIImageContext to use software rendering; see %@",
                  @"<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689233/ciimage-drawing-exc-bad-access>");
            options = @{ kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: @YES };
        }
        _cix = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:_cgx
                                       options:options];
        _rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    });
    float * data = CGBitmapContextGetData(_cgx);
    CGContextClearRect(_cgx, _rect);
    [_cix drawImage:processedImage
             inRect:_rect
           fromRect:_rect];
    NSData * pixelData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data
                                              length:_bytesPerRow * size.height
                                        freeWhenDone:NO];
    // For whatever bizarre reason, CoreGraphics uses big-endian floats (!)
    return [self byteswapPlanarFData:pixelData swapInPlace:NO];
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, I was quite surprised to see that the float pixel data came out of the CGBitmapContext in big-endian order. (I determined this only by trial and error.) Thus additional the method `-byteswapPlanarFData:swapInPlace:` was introduced, and all seemed well with the world... For a time.

But *now* I would like to render this processed data *back* into a `CGImage`.

Previously my code took the `float * data` buffer extracted above and used it directly to render a new `CGImage` and then wrap it up in an `NSImage`, like this:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, bytesPerRow * size.height, NULL);
CGImageRef renderedImage = CGImageCreate(size.width, size.height, 32, 32, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapFloatComponents, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:renderedImage
                                              size:size];
CGImageRelease(renderedImage);
```

So *now* I am doing this:

```
pixelData = [mumble imagePlanarFData:processedImage];
// Swap data back to how it was before...
pixelData = [mumble byteswapPlanarFData:pixelData
                            swapInPlace:YES];
float * data = (float *)[pixelData bytes];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, bytesPerRow * size.height, NULL);
CGImageRef renderedImage = CGImageCreate(size.width, size.height, 32, 32, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapFloatComponents, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:renderedImage
                                              size:size];
CGImageRelease(renderedImage);
```

The above does *not* work. Instead I get a corrupted image and a stream of complaints from CoreGraphics:

```
Mar 21 05:56:46 aoide.local LabCam[34235] <Error>: CMMConvLut::ConvertFloat 1 input (inf)
Mar 21 05:56:46 aoide.local LabCam[34235] <Error>: ApplySequenceToBitmap failed (-171)
Mar 21 05:56:46 aoide.local LabCam[34235] <Error>: ColorSyncTransformConvert - failed width = 160 height = 199 dstDepth = 7 dstLayout = 0 dstBytesPerRow = 1920 srcDepth = 7 srcLayout = 0 srcBytesPerRow = 640
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, found the problem... Turns out there was a left-over routine from before I added the byte-swapping call to `-imagePlanarFData:` that was *also* swapping the bytes in-place...

I would *still* like to hear some explanation for why CoreGraphics expects these values in big-endian byte order on our little-endian platform.

Comment: From http://lists.apple.com/archives/Quartz-dev//2011/Dec/msg00001.html: "As a bit of historical weirdness, Quartz defaults a non-existant endian flag as big-endian rather than host endian."