# Can NSView be made to use software rendering for CIImages?

Tags: cocoa, nsimageview, ciimage

From a previous question, 
[CIImage drawing EXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689233/ciimage-drawing-exc-bad-access),
I learned to work around a **CoreImage** issue by telling a `CIContext` to do software rendering. I am now trying to figure out a crasher that happens when AppKit tries to draw an `NSImageView` that I've set to display a `CIImage` using the code below:

```
- (void)setCIImage:(CIImage *)processedImage;
{
    NSSize size = [processedImage extent].size;
    if (size.width == 0) {
        [self setImage:nil];
        return;
    }
    NSData * pixelData = [[OMFaceRecognizer defaultRecognizer] imagePlanarFData:processedImage];
    LCDocument * document = [[[self window] windowController] document];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LCCapturedImageNotification
                                                        object:document
                                                      userInfo:@{ @"data": pixelData, @"size": [NSValue valueWithSize:size] }];
#if 1
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    static size_t bytesPerRow;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^ {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGray);
        bytesPerRow = size.width * sizeof(float);
    });
    // For whatever bizarre reason, CoreGraphics uses big-endian floats (!)
    const float * data = [[[OMFaceRecognizer defaultRecognizer] byteswapPlanarFData:pixelData
                                                                        swapInPlace:NO] bytes];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, bytesPerRow * size.height, NULL);
    CGImageRef renderedImage = CGImageCreate(size.width, size.height, 32, 32, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapFloatComponents, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:renderedImage
                                                  size:size];
    CGImageRelease(renderedImage);
#else
    NSCIImageRep * rep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:processedImage];
    NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];
    [image addRepresentation:rep];
#endif
    [self setImage:image];
}
```

Is there some way to get the `NSImageView` to use software rendering? I looked around in **IB** but I did not see anything that looked obviously promising…

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it wouldn't surprise me to learn that CG doesn't really handle grayscale float images gracefully. It might be fine, but I've run into issues like that it can't handle float RGBA data, it has to be ARGB (or maybe it was the reverse?). It's not very well documented what is supported, but I've seen it cause odd problems when you use an unsupported format.

Comment: OK, nevermind. I [looked it up](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE), and it does support that. Does adding the `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big` (or `Little`) constant to the bitmap info parameter in `CGImageCreate()` have any effect?

Comment: @user1118321: Ah, yes adding `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little` did indeed allow the gratuitous byte-swapping to be skipped… Thanks for that.